# How do I use MethodCall.invoke(someElementMatcher) to create a MethodCall representing a method I subsequently define in an instrumented type?

Tags: byte-buddy

I am using ByteBuddy to generate a class.

Prior to working with `DynamicType.Builder`, I was going to store a `MethodCall` as an instance variable:

```java
private final MethodCall frobCall =
  MethodCall.invoke(ElementMatchers.named("frob")); // here I invoke a method I'm going to define as part of the instrumented type
```

Then later in my generation logic for the instrumented type I define the `frob` method to do something:

```java
.defineMethod("frob")
.intercept(...etc....) // here I define frob to do something
```

…and I define the (let's say) `baz` method to invoke `frob`:

```java
.defineMethod("baz")
.withParameter(...) // etc.
.intercept(frobCall); // invokes "frob", which I've just defined above
```

(I am trying to keep this simple and may have mistyped something but I hope you can see the gist of what I'm trying to do.)

When I `make()` my `DynamicType`, I receive an error that indicates that the dynamic type does not define `frob`.  This is mystifying to me, because of course I have defined it, as you can see above.

Is there some restriction I am unaware of that prohibits `ElementMatchers` from identifying instrumented type methods that are defined later?  Do I really have to use `MethodDescription.Latent` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should match all methods of the instrumented type. If this is not happening as expected, please set a breakpoint in  `MethodCall.MethodLocator.ForElementMatcher` to see why the method is not showing up. I assume it is filtered by your method matcher.

I noticed however that it did not include private methods which is now fixed and will be released within Byte Buddy 1.10.18.

Comment: Aha; yes; the method in question is `private`.  Looking forward to 1.10.18!